# Fill missing dates with zero in a data.table by an inplace way

Tags: r, data.table

Firstly,
**I checked the similar questions and answers but couldn't find an inplace solution for implementing solutions for a huge table**. As a toy data, my data structure is like this;

```
  product location date       value
  <chr>   <chr>    <date>     <int>
1 A       X        2022-01-01    22
2 A       Y        2022-01-03    82
3 B       Y        2022-01-03    27
4 C       Z        2022-01-01    74
5 C       Z        2022-01-02    58
6 C       Z        2022-01-03    68
7 C       Z        2022-01-04    75
```

To reproduce;

```
df <- structure(list(product = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"), 
    location = c("X", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z"), date = structure(c(18993, 
    18995, 18995, 18993, 18994, 18995, 18996), class = "Date"), 
    value = c(22L, 82L, 27L, 74L, 58L, 68L, 75L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

I want to duplicate each product&location combination for a date range (`2022-01-01` to `2022-01-04`) and fill `value` column with zero.

The desired output should look like;

```
   product location date       value
   <chr>   <chr>    <date>     <int>
 1 A       X        2022-01-01    22
 2 A       X        2022-01-02     0
 3 A       X        2022-01-03     0
 4 A       X        2022-01-04     0
 5 A       Y        2022-01-01     0
 6 A       Y        2022-01-02     0
 7 A       Y        2022-01-03    82
 8 A       Y        2022-01-04     0
 9 B       Y        2022-01-01     0
10 B       Y        2022-01-02     0
11 B       Y        2022-01-03    27
12 B       Y        2022-01-04     0
13 C       Z        2022-01-01    74
14 C       Z        2022-01-02    58
15 C       Z        2022-01-03    68
16 C       Z        2022-01-04    75
```

I am familiar with the solutions by `tidyr::complete` and making distinct tables and cross join them, but my original data is very huge and these solutions are memory inefficient for me. I also tried to split data into smaller parts then fill their missing dates with zero but again in that time I couldn't reunion them because of the memory issue.

How can I fill the missing dates with zero in an **inplace** way ?

Thanks in advance.